# rake repeats the same test many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, ruby-1.9, minitest

I'm adding a new (plain old) ruby class to my Rails app. I have a minimal unit test for the class:

```
require 'minitest_helper'
class ReportOptionTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @report_option = Cmdx::ReportGenerator::ReportOption.new( "testing123" )
  end

  def test_depends_on
    assert @report_option.depends_on.empty?
  end
end
```

If I run just this test via rake, it runs, as I expected, but it runs *six times*, which I did not:

```
$ time rake test TEST=test/unit/report_generator/report_option_test.rb 
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Run options: --seed 64427

# Running tests:
.

Finished tests in 0.003272s, 305.6309 tests/s, 305.6309 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Run options: --seed 17980

# Running tests:
.

Finished tests in 0.003284s, 304.4809 tests/s, 304.4809 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Run options: --seed 45845

# Running tests:
.

Finished tests in 0.003267s, 306.0590 tests/s, 306.0590 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Run options: --seed 49526

# Running tests:
.

Finished tests in 0.003258s, 306.9620 tests/s, 306.9620 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Run options: --seed 53716

# Running tests:
.

Finished tests in 0.003246s, 308.1155 tests/s, 308.1155 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Run options: --seed 44898

# Running tests:
.

Finished tests in 0.003272s, 305.6556 tests/s, 305.6556 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

real   0m34.999s
user   0m32.034s
sys    0m1.440s
```

I note that [this page](http://flavio.castelli.name/2010/05/28/rails_execute_single_test/) mentions a similar issue. I don't understand what's going on, and whether there's some config setting I need to change to just run the test once, and, frankly, make running the tests finish faster.

Versions:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-linux]
$ rake -V
rake, version 10.0.3
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.12
```

Comment: Are you using minitest-rails? If so this is a bug.

Comment: blowmage: I am using minitest-rails 0.3.0. Do you mean this is a known bug, or something that I need to log a bugrep for?

Comment: Not a known bug. Open an issue please.